# How to prove complex identity?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

I proved that $z^6+z^3+1 = (z^2-2z\cos(\frac{2π}{9})+1)(z^2-2z\cos(\frac{4π}{9})+1)(z^2-2z\cos(\frac{8π}{9})+1)$

Using this, how to show that $$2\cos(3 \theta)+1=8\left(\cos \theta-\cos\left(\frac{2π}{9}\right)\right)\left(\cos \theta-\cos\left(\frac{4π}{9}\right)\right)\left(\cos\theta-\cos\left(\frac{8π}{9}\right)\right)$$

I know it involves some trig substitution but I'm not sure how. Help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by $z^3$:
$$z^3+z^{-3}+1=(z+z^{-1}-2\cos(2\pi/9))(z+z^{-1}-2\cos(4\pi/9))(z+z^{-1}-2\cos(8\pi/9))$$
Put in $z=\exp(i\phi)$, noting that $z+z^{-1}=2\cos\phi$ and
$z^3+z^{-3}=2\cos3\phi$:
$$2\cos3\phi+1=(2\cos\phi-2\cos(2\pi/9))(2\cos\phi-2\cos(4\pi/9))(2\cos\phi-2\cos(8\pi/9)).$$

Comment: How to get the RHS of first line?

Comment: Divide each factor by $z$.

Comment: You have 3 factors on the RHS multiplied together. Pull a factor of $z$ out of each of the 3 factors, pulling out a total of 3 factors of $z$, or $z^3$. Simplified example of what I'm describing:
$$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3) = x(1+1/x)x(1+2/x)x(1+3/x) = x^3(1+1/x)(1+2/x)(1+3/x)$$